# I can't access mipmap file from layout file

Tags: java, android, xml

I work in Android Studio and it's been an hour since I searched how to solve my problem.
I'm only trying to use a mipmap as an icon; so I have the line

```
android:icon="@mipmap/new"
```

But it does not work and it gets underlined in red.

Do you have any idea on how to get that fixed?

Comment: When you hover your mouse over the red underline, what does the popup error message tell you? Do you actually have a `new` image in a `res/mipmap-*/` directory? Also, since `new` is a reserved word in Java, you may not be able to define a resource with that name.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes, I just imported an image in the mipmaps. Its name is new.png. Do I have something to do before I can use it?

Comment: When you hover your mouse over the red underline, what does the popup error message tell you?

Comment: @CommonsWare I just remembered you told me its name can't be "new". This was the problem. What's weird is that it didn't help me complete the resource path for mipmaps whereas for drawables it works...

Anyways, thank you very much!